# Is there a native way of connecting with HANA DB using sap-cloud-sdk for JS?

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to connect with HANA DB using Cloud SDK project. Is there a native approach to connect HANA using sdk or we need to use hana-client package for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@sap/hana-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/hana-client) package is the official package for connecting to an SAP HANA instance in Node.js. The SAP Cloud SDK does not currently offer any alternative way to connect, nor any functionality on top of this. If there's something you think the SAP Cloud SDK should offer, but that's missing, you're welcome to open a feature request in the [repository](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk).